# Monitor multiple values at any time

Tags: jquery

I have a table between 1 and 100 rows. In each row there are two input-fields.

**1)** `.type`
**2)** `[id*=name]`

At the end of the table there is a button with the id `#send`.
If the value of `.type` is *A, B or C* and the value of `[id*=name]` is empty the button should be disabled, otherwise enabled. This should be monitored by row for the whole table at any time.

e.g. 99 rows have the value *A, B or C* and the value of `[id*=name]` is not empty but 1 row has the value *A, B or C* and the value of `[id*=name]` is empty. **=>**  the button should be disabled.

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: please make sure that your question is understandable.

Comment: thank you for your great input! I found a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution.

```
$( ".type, [id*=name]" ).change(function() {

    var obj = {};

    $('tbody tr').each(function (i) {
        obj[i] = { type: $(this).find(".type").val(), name: $(this).find("[id*=name]").val() };
    }); 

    $.each(obj, function (index, value) {           
        if (( value['type'] == "A" || value['type'] == "B" || value['type'] == "C" ) && value['name'] == "") {
            $('#send').prop('disabled', true);
            return;
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<div><input value="" type="text" class="type"><input value="" type="text" id="name_1"></div>
<div><input value="" type="text" class="type"><input value="" type="text" id="name_2"></div>
<div><input value="" type="text" class="type"><input value="" type="text" id="name_3"></div>
<div><input value="" type="text" class="type"><input value="" type="text" id="name_4"></div>
<div><input value="" type="text" class="type"><input value="" type="text" id="name_5"></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit"></div>

<script>
$('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
$(document).on('change',$('.type'),function(e){
    if( $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; }).length == 0 ) {
        $('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: thank you @Alain Nisam for your input - I have found a working solution - see my answer.

Comment: No problem Mike. If I may, your solution may work, but you are doing a lot of looping when you don't need to do any at all since looping is very inefficient